# How to get ngForm variable reference in the component class?

Tags: dart, angular, angular2-forms

Given the following...

### .html

```
<form (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()"
          #heroForm = "ngForm">
      {{diagnostic}}
      <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "name">Name</label>
        <input type = "text"
               class = "form-control"
               required
               [(ngModel)] = "model.name"
               ngControl = "name"
               #name = "ngForm"
               #spy>
        <p *ngIf = "name.dirty"
           class = "alert alert-danger">
          Name is required
        </p>
        <!--<p [hidden] = "name.dirty"-->
           <!--class = "alert alert-danger">-->
          <!--Name is required-->
        <!--</p>-->
      </div>
```

..

..is it possible to get the `#name = "ngForm"` (ngForm) reference in the .dart component to allow manipulation? Any suggestion and correction is welcome.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

import this -

```
import {ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
```

Just add this field with the annotation to the class

```
// Dart syntax
@ViewChild('heroForm') NgForm heroForm;
```

You can't use it in the constructor though because it is only set later. In `ngAfterViewInit` or event handlers for user input you can use it without limitations.

Comment: Just looking at the above response, should   `@ViewChild('name') NgControl` name return the name control?

Comment: I found this confusing in your question. `@ViewChild('name')` assigns a reference of the element that has the template variable `#name`. Alternatively you can pass a type `@ViewChild(NgForm)`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@ViewChild('heroForm') heroForm: NgForm`?

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk it's Dart syntax. See the tags below the question ;-) Thanks for the hint anyway.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer so this means if I want to access this form in my component (to check if it really appears--unit testing) I can use inside the class like this:  this.comp.name after I have imported your 2 lines???

Comment: And why are there 2 ngForms tho, one name and the other one heroForm?? I dont understand this

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective and https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm have `exportAs: 'ngForm'` and if you want to get a reference on one of these you have to use `#foo="ngForm"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer please have a look at this very explained question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970638/can%C2%B4t-access-dom-properties-in-angular  Thanks.