# Error-Property value does not exist in type name string

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, angular-test

I hope this question clarifies so many people about testing template driven forms that Angular documentation barely mentions. I have an input inside this form that I want to test.
I want to test a simple DOM in Angular using Jasmine. This is a template driven form using NgForm like this:

```
<form name="editForm" role="form"  novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">
    <input #inputtotest type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="field_nombre"
        [(ngModel)]="paciente.nombre" required/>
```

I want to test only:

- If this input for this label sends data (**paciente.nombre**) using NgModel or better if its Property is paciente.model.

According to this responses we can use `ViewChild` for that: [use of viewchild on DOM](https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/) [How to get ngForm variable reference in the component class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820706/how-to-get-ngform-variable-reference-in-the-component-class)

My component file is like this:

```
//all the other imports
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   ...
})

export class PacienteDialogComponent implements OnInit 
{
    @ViewChild('inputtotest') inputtotest: **ElementRef**;  //Create a viewchild of my input s I can obtain its value
    paciente: Paciente; //Paciente is a modal that initializes the nombre
    ...
}
```

And my spec file to write the tests for the form is like this:

```
//All te Angular imports
describe('Component Tests', () => {

    describe('Paciente Management Dialog Component', () => {
        let comp: PacienteDialogComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<PacienteDialogComponent>;
        //starts my code
        let input: HTMLElement;

        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                .....angular imports                        


        }));

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PacienteDialogComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
            input = `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('inputtotest')).nativeElement;`
        });
```

Tests:

```
it ('The form should call save method on submit', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges(); 
    spyOn(comp,'save');
    savebutton.click();
    expect(comp.save).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
}));



it ('The form should have the input for paciente.nombre', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();


expect(inputname.getAttribute.value).toEqual(paciente.nombre);

}));
```

Now I have obtained the input as a HTMLelement and I do not find any way on how to check that it is Equal to ngModel value that is paciente.nombre. I do it like in the example and the result is the error:

Property value does not exist in type name string.
Have I done something wrong?

Comment: What are ** for?

Comment: Maybe from code in bold

Comment: maybe, with `By.css()` you should use a classname, like `By.css('.inputtotest')` and `<input #inputtotest class="inputtotest".../>`